# Stripe class for div

Tags: jquery, html, css, zebra-striping

I have a long list of multiple div... let's say 20 div

All wrap in another one..

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="xyz"> text text </div>
 <div class="xyz"> text text </div>
 <div class="xyz"> text text </div>
 <div class="xyz"> text text </div>
 <div class="xyz"> text text </div>
.... etc
</div>
```

i like to add class "grey" in one out of two div and make it zebra !
jquery please !

Comment: excuse.. some corrections done (id/class)

Comment: Actually your old code was fine. Your new one is invalid because you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: In fact, you don't need the xyz class at all. If all elements inside another element have the same class you might as well remove it and select them by `#main > div`.

Comment: not ALL MY CODE... work with OTHER code... have to life and get thing done...

Comment: Are you saying this is code you can't change, but it does have multiple id's? That's a tough job to be in, I've been there and it's annoying. Still, my answer should work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('.xyz:odd').addClass('grey');`

Do mind that 'grey' is not a semantic classname. Better call id 'odd' or 'zebra' or something. If you'd make up your mind and change the odd color to blue your classname would be real strange :P

Answer (score 2):

jQuery makes it just about as easy as it can be:

`$('#main>div.xyz:even').addClass('grey');`

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about older versions of IE, you can do this using CSS alone:

```
.xyz:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: ...;
}

.xyz:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: ...;
}
```

Comment: i care !... must be ie6 friendly !

Comment: unfortunately even IE8 doesn't support this.. big bummer.